# Writing a Makefile to generate the modified, assembly, relocatable and executable file from a C program

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

I'm using CentOS to write a Makefile to generate these files from a C program:

1. `hello.i` (Modified source program, text)
2. `hello.s` (Assembly program, text)
3. `hello.o` (Relocatable object program, binary)
4. `hello` (Executable object program, binary)

The idea is to open each file to see its content.

C program (called hello.c)

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
   printf("Hello, World!");
   return 0;
}
```

Makefile

```
all: hello

hello:
      gcc -I hello.c -o hello.i

hello.o:
      gcc -c hello.c -o hello.o

hello.s:
      gcc -S hello.i -o hello.s

hello.i:
      gcc ???

clean:
      rm -rf *.o hello
```

Also, a clean command to delete all.

Error that I receive when I do: `make all`

> compilation terminated. make: *** [hello] Error 4

I know that there is a single command to generate all at once, but, I want to do it by steps. This is my first Makefile that I try to do and I'm not 100% familiar yet.

What I'm doing wrong, maybe a wrong flag?

My goal is to generate all the files mentioned above to open them and see their content.

Comment: You didn't declare any of your dependencies. (Also, where is the rest of the error message?)

Comment: @melpomene Hi, that is the complete error that I received in terminal. Dependencies? should I add at the right of ":" the name of the file needed? I thought that the command will do that. Can you help me a little bit? I'm kinda lost here.

Comment: If that is the complete error message, what command are you actually running that produces this message?

Comment: What are you trying to do with `gcc -I hello.c -o hello.i`?

Comment: Also, it's not true that that's the complete error.  That may be the only error message _make_ prints, but there are other errors printed before that, from the `gcc` command.  This message (`Error 4`) is simply  make telling you that the command it invoked (`gcc -I hello.c -o hello.i`) failed with exit code 4.  To know why that command failed, you have to look at the errors that command generated, which will be output before the error you showed us.

Comment: @melpomene I was running just `make`. @Chelmy88 I was trying to generate the .i file, but, now I know that the correct flag for this is `-E`. @MadScientist Thanks for the link, was useful. Also, how can I tell the `make` command to show the entire log/errors ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without the `hello.i`, which is for me unclear what is should be, your make file should look like that:

```
all: hello hello.s

hello: hello.c hello.o
    gcc hello.o -o hello

hello.o: hello.c
    gcc -c hello.c -o hello.o

hello.s: hello.c
    gcc -S hello.c -o hello.s

clean:
    rm -rf *.o
```

You issue is that in Makefile, after the semicolon you should indicate the dependencies (the files the current output will need to be produced).

In you case, `all` declares that `hello`and `hello.s` are required. Then `make` looks to produce them using the given commands. `Hello` declares that `hello.o` is required, so it also look to the given command to produce it.

`hello.o` and `hello.o` declare that `hello.c` is required, so `make` will check if it finds the file and in yes it will run the `gcc` command. Now that `hello.o` is produced, it will go back to produce `hello`.

The commands should be indented with proper tabs, so if you copy paste check that you have tabs and no multiple spaces.

Comment: By the way, the `hello.i` is a file that can be generated in the preprocessing phase. The preprocessor modifies the original C program according to directives that begin with the # character and other stuff. The result is another C program, typically with the `.i`. suffix. The only thing that lacks in your example is the `hello.i` which is not generated. Try to add it to have a complete solution for future users. Another user said that the correct flag to generate the `.i` file is `-E`. I have tried it and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you did not declare a recipe for `hello.i`, and you did not declare the appropriate dependencies for the other recipes. Additionally, the command line option to create `hello.i` is `-E`, not `-I`.

Let's see:

- `hello` needs the file `hello.o`
- `hello.i` needs the file `hello.c`
- `hello.o` needs the file `hello.c`
- `hello.s` needs the file `hello.i`

This would be the correct makefile:

```
all: hello

hello: hello.o
    gcc hello.o -o hello

hello.i: hello.c
    gcc -E hello.c -o hello.i

hello.o: hello.c
    gcc -c hello.c -o hello.o

hello.s: hello.i
    gcc -S hello.i -o hello.s

clean:
    rm -rf *.o hello
```

Additionally, taking advantage of Make special variables, you can use `$@` to indicate the current recipe, and `$<` to indicate the first dependency, making it less verbose, like this:

```
all: hello

hello: hello.o
    gcc $< -o $@

hello.i: hello.c
    gcc -E $< -o $@

hello.o: hello.c
    gcc -c $< -o $@

hello.s: hello.i
    gcc -S $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -rf *.o hello
```